# how to have object always travel the shortest distance towards/to point it is already following

Tags: android, path, logic, andengine, touch-event

a. I have an object.
b. when the user touches the screen it will ease/tween to the users touch coordinate.
c. if the user drags their finger then the object will follow that path simply by traversing the path made by the input data from the motion event ACTION_MOVE.

how do i make it so that the object takes the shortest distance to the users touch coordinates instead of following the exact path that they create?

Eventually, the object should catch up to the users touch coordinate.

```
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    this.getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    final Scene scene = new Scene();
    scene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

    final int x = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
    final int y = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;
    final Sprite face = new Sprite(x, y, this.mFaceTextureRegion);
    scene.registerTouchArea(face);
    scene.attachChild(face);
    //face.setPosition(134, 200);
    //face.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(500, x, 100, y, 200, EaseQuadIn.getInstance())); 

    scene.setOnSceneTouchListener(new IOnSceneTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene,TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
            int facePosX = (int) (pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - face.getWidth() / 2);
            int facePosY = (int) (pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - face.getHeight() / 2);

            if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                face.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(1, face.getX(), facePosX,face.getY(), facePosY, EaseQuadIn.getInstance()));                
               }
            return true;            
            }
    });


    scene.setTouchAreaBindingEnabled(true);
    return scene;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, and get start and end co-ordinates, and move object accordingly.

So your start point would be on ACTION_DOWN and End Pont be on ACTION_UP.